# TKinter redirect terminal output

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I made a software in Python using Tkinter, for the graphics, and ctypes in order to interface to some C libraries the firm gave me. 
A lot of operations I do print an output on the terminal, so I was wondering: is there an easy way for redirecting these output messages to another tkinter window? 
For instance, I'd like to print a cout << "Hello World!" in a new tkinter winter, linked to the root one, instead of the terminal, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `sys.stdout`:

```py
class WriteToWindow():
    def write(self, text):
        ...  # write text to your window

    def flush(self):
        pass  # this method should exist, but doesn't need to do anything

import sys
sys.stdout = WriteToWindow()
```

Now everything written to stdout, which includes calls to `print`, will be sent to your `WriteToWindow` class.

Comment: Could you make an example using this excerpt of code?

libC = CDLL('/usr/lib/stuff.so', mode = RTLD_GLOBAL)

def func():
      libC.Show('TEST')  #this is a simple function doing cout << 'TEST \n';

a = Button(root, text='TEST', command=func)

Comment: After some thinking I solved the issue thanks to your comment. Thank you!